# How to validate filename in bash script?

Tags: bash, validation, filenames

**A little bit about my application:**

I am writing a small application in bash script. The application must store personal settings to home directory.

My settings are in the form of a key/value pair which will be stored as filename/content:

```
for example:
~/my-github-app
    ├── github-account
    ├── github-token
```

**My current solution for adding a key/value:**

```
read KEY
read VALUE
# FIXME! should check for for valid filename.
#        user can do injection hack by KEY="../../path/to/yourfile"
echo $VALUE > ~/my-github-app/$KEY
```

**What is the simplest and safe way to validate $KEY?**

- A built-in function?
- A regular expression?

*I really need a reusable solution, not just for this application.*

Edit:

"validate filename" mean check string for proper filename format, accepted by OS.

- "bob" : good filename format
- ""    : bad because filename can not be empty
- "*"   : ?
- "/"   : ?
- "con" : ?
  ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to make something secure is to use a whitelist. Which means instead of blacklisting bad characters you allow good ones. The reason why blacklists will always fail is that you can't blacklist all of the weird characted, you'd always forget something. Especially if you're working with unicode strings.

Filenames could contain anything. According to wikipedia:

> Ext4 Allowed characters in filenames: All bytes except NUL ('\0') and '/'

Which means that whole bash scripts could be valid filenames.
So, if I were you, I would only allow a-zA-Z as valid characters. Problem solved.

That's how you do it:

```
# if [[ $key =~ [^a-zA-Z] ]]; then # or this. Whatever makes more sense to you
if ! [[ $key =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; then
    echo 'Wrong key. Only a-zA-Z characters are allowed' >&2 # write to stderr
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank for infomation about Ext4. I have the same idea about whitelist :), https://github.com/damphat/kv-bash/blob/master/kv-bash

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Aleks-Daniel Jakimenko-A.'s answer, following script checks following conditions, If all conditions are set then `True` is returned:

- `a-z`
- `A-Z`
- `0-9`
- underscore (`_`)
- dash (`-`)
- period (`.`)
- Max length is 255
- First character should be a character or number: {`a-z` or `A-z` or `0-9`}

*my_script.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
# To run: bash my_script.sh <my_string_is>

key=$1
val=$(echo "${#key}")

if [[ $key == "" ]]; then
   echo "False";
   exit
fi

if [[ $key == "." ]] || [[ $key == ".." ]]; then
    # "." and ".." are added automatically and always exist, so you can't have a
    # file named . or .. // https://askubuntu.com/a/416508/660555
    echo "False";
    exit
fi

if [ $val -gt 255 ]; then
   # String's length check
   echo "False";
   exit
fi

if ! [[ $key =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z._-]+$ ]]; then
    # Checks whether valid characters exist
    echo "False";
    exit
fi

_key=$(echo $key | cut -c1-1)
if ! [[ $_key =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z.]+$ ]]; then
    # Checks the first character
    echo "False";
    exit
fi

echo "True";
```

Comment: Any reason not to check the string length first? The argument size limit seems to be about ≈2MB on a lot of systems, so matching all that against a regex is possibly a wasted effort if we return false later anyway.

Comment: There is no specific reason. I updated my answer to check string length first.@Aleks-DanielJakimenko-A.

Comment: Why shouldn't the 1st character be a dot ? In Unix and Unix-like systems, a that will create a hidden file, with a valid file name.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes First character can be dot. I updated my answer based on your comment. Just heads up for not having filename "." or ".."

Comment: @alper, thanks a lot for a great function.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if a file already exists, use the `test` command and use it like this for your validation :

```
if [[ ! -e "$KEY" ]]
then
    #file doet not exists
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to validate, just that a key doesn't contain any path info?

```
KEY=$(basename $KEY)
```

This would remove any parts of the KEY that are part of the path. That said, there are plenty of things the user could enter that would probably be a bad idea. Can you perhaps have a list of allowed keys, then reject anything that isn't in that list?

If you're trying to see if a file is writable, you could check if a) it exists and is writable (`-w`) or b) just try to write to it and check for errors.

Comment: Hi zigdon, basename extract filename from path, not for validate filename. A valid filename is creatable filename.

Comment: That's what I was trying to find out - what do you mean by "validating" KEY there.

Comment: yes "list of allowed keys" by a regular expression, thank zigdon

Comment: If you have a list of allowed keys, I wouldn't use a regular expression, just check it against that list. Say, in each directory prepopulate the keys allowed, then allow overwriting one if it already exists, but not creating new ones.